# 2dimensional array with malloc

Tags: c

I am trying to use calloc and malloc in order to create a 2 dimensional array. My logic until now was to firstly create an array of integer pointers with calloc and then use malloc in order to create the second dimension. This is my code:

```
enter code here


    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        int N,M,i=0,j=0;

        printf("Give the dimensions");
        scanf("%d%d",&N,&M);
        printf("You gave N: %d and M: %d\n",N,M);

        int **a=(int**)calloc(N,sizeof(int*));

        for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            a[i]=(int*)malloc(M*sizeof(int));
        }

        printf("The array that was created resigns on addresses\n");
        for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<M; j++)
            {
                printf("addr: %p\n",a[i,j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

With this, I want to make sure that I create the array I want. Giving dimensions N=2 and M=2 (just an example), I take the addresses (for example): (0,0): 0x00001, (0,1):0x00003, (1,0): 0x00001, (1,1): 0x00003. Therefore, I don't get a 2 dimensional array, but just a simple array with only 2 positions. Can you please point out my coding mistake? I can't find it... :S

Comment: You should check the return values as good pratice, even if you are confident that your system will return successfully. Also `s/resigns/resides/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong usage of the index access operator `[]`. You're not accessing the i-th row and the j-column but instead only the `j` element because you use the comma operator:

```
a[i,j] == a[j]
```

Instead you have to access a given row and then access a cell:

```
a[i][j]
```

Note that this will **not** return an address but an `int`:

```
typeof a       == int **
typeof a[i]    == int *
typeof a[i][j] == int
```

If you still want to know the address of your entries you would have to use `&a[i][j]` or `a[i]+j`.

Comment: Thx a lot guys!! I was getting no warning or anything for that stupid mistake of mine. Thanks a lot :))

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("addr: %p\n",a[i,j]);
```

That is

```
printf("addr: %p\n",a[j]);
```

You're using the comma operator there.

To access the `j`-th element of the `i`-th array, you'd use

```
a[i][j]
```

But that would be an `int` here, and not a pointer, so the `printf` would invoke undefined behaviour with the `%p` conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just did what you said.
        for(j=0; j<M; j++)
        {
            printf("addr: %p\n",a[j]);
        }
Nothins changed. I still have the same problem.